# MYSQL: re-order/sort table by field name in 250+ field table and save?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with over 250 fields and I am trying to find a quick way to re-sort and save it so I can much easier find the fields for debugging..

eg I run...

```
describe master_rets_table
```

and get...

```
Field       Type            Null    Key             Extra
-----       ----            ----    ---             -----
id          int(11)         NO      PRI            auto_increment
agent_id    varchar(50)     YES         
rets_system varchar(20)     YES         
rets_key    varchar(25)     YES         
listing_id  varchar(25)     YES     MUL         
...
...
...
```

I try...

```
ALTER TABLE master_rets_table ORDER BY Field asc
```

and of course it doesn't work (`[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Field' in 'order clause'`)

Comment: You need to run a SELECT query before the concept of sorting even applies.

Comment: Wow, 250+ fields in a table... Maybe some SQL UI clients can auto-sort columns. It's not a MySQL thing. You sort records, not columns.

Comment: yes i know...very suboptimal but i have to work with what i'm given.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to change the order of columns

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHANGE COLUMN yourcolumn VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL FIRST;
```

Or,instead of FIRST use

```
..AFTER someOtherColumn
```

Comment: hmmmm....getting warmer, but it is still surprising to me that there isn't some "meta" way to easily sort fieldnames in a table using standard SQL syntax